# How do I remove a language from a Beaker notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

I've removed all the cells that refer to a certain language, and now I want to remove it from my notebook entirely. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Notebook menu, and open the Language Manager and click the button for the language you want to remove. The indicator would be green before you click it. The buttons are actually toggles. Make sure you have first removed all cells from the notebook that use that language. When the language is successfully removed, the indicator will go gray.